# Constraint on values, oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I would like to have a table in my Oracle database where the values of an `attribute1` (values may change) can't be greater than the value (fixed) of `attribute2`.

Is it possible to enforce such a rule?
Is it possible to make a value impossible to change after the insert ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disallowing `attribute1` from being larger than `attribute2` can be done with a `check` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
ADD CONSTRAINT attribute2_greater_check
CHECK (attribute2 >= attribute1)
```

Preventing update of `attribute2` can be done with a `trigger` that raises an error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mytable_attribute2_update_tr
BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :NEW.attribute2 != :OLD.attribute2
   THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'attribute2 cannot be updated');
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you, it makes me understood constraints and triggers :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is to use an appropriate `CONSTRAINT` when creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column1 integer,
  column2 integer not null,

  CONSTRAINT constraint_name CHECK (column1 <= column2)
);

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(1,1); //ok
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(2,1); //gives an error
```

Such constraints can use any fields in the table at hand, but may not access other tables via a subselect.

**EDIT:** I just realized you also asked another question ... that has been answered already by @Mureinik.